# Determining whether a subspace is disconnected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Z = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x+y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology.

I'm trying to determine whether $Z$ is disconnected. I can't seem to find any obvious separations of this subspace.

And I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a connected space since it is path-connected.

So I'm tempted to say that $Z$ must be connected as well. Any ideas on how to go about proving this?

Comment: I assume $a + b$ is supposed to be $x + y$?

Comment: If so, then here's a hint. Try showing that
$$Z = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x + y = n\},$$
then plotting some of these sets in this union. What do you notice?

Comment: @TheoBendit What prevented you from posting this as an answer? By the way, I love your description on your profile!

Comment: So plotting those lines, we can create a separation by considering the region of the $xy$-plane where $y > -x+\frac{1}{2}$, and the region where $y < -x + \frac{1}{2}$. Call these regions $A$ and $B$ respectively (which are both open in $\mathbb{R^2}$). Then $A \cap Z$ and $B \cap Z$ are open in $Z$ and form a separation of $Z$. Hence, $Z$ is disconnected.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks! In answer to your question, a mixture of impatience in waiting for my first comment to be addressed, and not being sure that the asker would respond to my hint.

Answer (score 1):

$O=\{(x,y)\mid x+y > \frac12\}$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ (as $s^{-1}[(\frac12, +\infty)]$, where $s(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$). So is $O'=\{(x,y)\mid  x+y < \frac12\}$ for similar reasons.

And $Z=(O \cap Z) \cup (O' \cap Z)$ is a partition of $Z$ into two relatively open disjoint open sets. So $Z$ is disconnected.